# synchronize a restored local copy of git repository

Tags: git, github, backup

My hard drive crashed recently and I went back to a recent backup of all my data.
However I had some changes in a local git repository that I had not committed before the failure. Now I want to bring everything back to where it was before the hard drive failure.

That is, I have a local copy of a folder that used to be connected to the git repository. However all the .git folders are missing. How can I synchronize the local copy with the repository, while keeping all the modifications that I had and did not commit to the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simply can:

- clone you repo
- overwrite its content with your backup local copy
- ask git diff to display all the changes, add, and commit what you need to version.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have changed files without actual git commits. In this case you should just re-clone you remote repository and apply changes from your local folder to cloned repo. But all you commits (I mean git commits) are lost.